# change config-overrides.js location

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, sonarqube

Hello dear stackoverflow users. I have a react project. I have a config-overrides.js file that comes with react-app-rewired in this project, and Sonarqube analyzes this file even though it shouldn't, and I can't pass the coverage. I know that moving this file to a place other than the main directory will solve my problem. For example, I need to move it to the src/config path, but when I just move it, my tests do not work because the project searches for this file in the main path and gives me the cannot find module error. How can I notify the path of config-overrides.js to my project after changing this path? Can you help me ?

my tsconfig file :

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "tests"
   ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

If you want to see the code of another file, please ask me for it